# Laravel Form:date gives null

Tags: php, laravel-blade, php-8, laravel-10

When submitting the below I receive null value of 'birth_date'.

```
{{ Form::date('birth_date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'format' => 'Y-m-d']) }}
```

Also, I noticed that when user has selected a date let's say "1990-12-24", and then select other input fields before submitting the value for date selected changes to "mm/dd/yyyy".

what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds silly,but I figured out. Infact to be specific I am reformatting someone's code, I found out inside the div of the form there was this `id="demo-dp-txtinput"`, after removing this everthing worked fine.

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="demo-dp-txtinput">                                  
     {{ Form::date('birth_date',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'format' => 'Y-m-d', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Date of Birth']) }}
      @if ($errors->has('birth_date'))
           <span class="help-block">
             <strong>{{ $errors->first('birth_date') }}</strong></span>
     @endif
   </div>
```

I